# Однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимися союзами

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли сказать, что здесь однородные члены "временных и финансовых" образуют смысловое единство и поэтому запятые не ставятся?

См. Вода давно сбыла в Тереке и быстро сбегала и сохла по канавам. Пройти огонь и воду и медные трубы.

Но в силу временных или финансовых или иных обстоятельств нет возможности надлежаще оформить заявочные материалы.

Answer (score 1):

Ой, нет... Так уж точно нельзя оставлять. *В силу временных (финансовых или иных) обстоятельств* – я бы вот так сделал.

Comment: А просто запятыми можно обойтись? Просто однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимися перед всеми, кроме первого, союзами.

Comment: Так это врЕменные обстоятельства или временнЫе? Если второе, то это все однородные члены.

Answer (score 1):

При двукратном повторении других союзов, кроме ***и,*** запятая ставится всегда: 
Ср.: Колоть беспрестанно мне глаза цыганской жизнью или глупо, или безжалостно (А. Остр.)

См.Академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант (с убиранием одного ***или***):

*Но в силу временных финансовых или иных обстоятельств нет возможности надлежаще оформить заявочные материалы.*

===============================

Да призадумался...

Имеем:

> Но в силу временных или финансовых или иных обстоятельств нет
>   возможности надлежаще оформить заявочные материалы.

Автор этого предложения утверждает, что *заявочные материалы не будут оформлены надлежащим образом.* Но почему не будут -- оказывается, и сам не знает. *"Или, или, или..."*

Предложение, по-моему, нужно перестроить, разобравшись с тем, что хотел сказать автор. Ну а потом уже думать и о пунктуационных знаках.

Answer (score 0):

**Редакция предложения зависит от смысла**

1) Но в силу временнЫх, финансовых или иных обстоятельств нет возможности надлежаще оформить заявочные материалы. Однородные отношения.

Временной - связанный со временем.

2) Но в силу врЕменных  (финансовых или иных)  обстоятельств нет возможности надлежаще оформить заявочные материалы. Неоднородные отношения.

Но в силу врЕменных финансовых (или иных) обстоятельств нет возможности надлежаще оформить заявочные материалы. Неоднородные отношения.

Временный - непостоянный.